# Storage gateway/File gateway on using EC2 instance - AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-storage-gateway

What is the recommended EC2 instance type for creating storage/file gateway in AWS.

- Compute/memory/Storage optimized?
- Also what is the criteria to be considered while allocating the size of ebs for cache? say if i have about 100k files and each of around 5 MB

This is for creating SMB/NFS file share from S3